# Joules To Move A Kilogram In Space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy

If roughly ten joules lifts one kg on earth one meter, how many in space?

Meter / joule/kilogram

Kilogram/meter/joule

Comment: How many what? Meters? Joules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply an infinitesimal force to accelerate your 1kg infinitesimally so that it has a non zero velocity, and allow it to travel 1 metre in an infinite amount of time, by using an infinitesimal amount of energy.

Or you can apply a huge force to accelerate your 1kg mass quickly, which consumes a large amount of energy.

In other words your question is under defined.

Comment: @t.c That is pretty much what I thought.