# Joules to do something

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

If my very limited understanding is correct, then, not accounting for gravity:

1 Newton can move 1 kilogram 1m

But, can 2 Newtons move 1 kilogram 2 meters?

Is this because 1 Newton = acceleration of 1/ms, so, 2 Newtons would result in a speed of 2 m/s? Or would it be 1 m/s lasting twice as long?

So what does a joule do: accelerate or just move?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137920/2451

Answer (score 2):

You have an incorrect understanding of forces, accelerations and velocities. A force of 1 Newton can *accelerate* a 1 kg mass at a rate of 1 m/s/s (often written as 1 m/s$^2$). A force of 2 Newtons can accelerate the same 1 kg mass at a rate of 2 m/s/s.

We relate the accelerations, velocities and positions via the [kinematic equations](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-6/Kinematic-Equations); for this case we can use
$$
x_{new}(t)=x_{old}+vt+\frac12at^2
$$
where the $old$ subscript is the initial position and the $new$ subscript indicates where we will be after $t$ seconds due to an initial velocity, $v$, and acceleration, $a$. If we consider the object as initially stationary, $v=0$, and at position $x_{old}=0$, then in 1 second the two forces give us total distances of
$$
x_{new}(t=1\,{\rm s})=\begin{cases}\frac12\,{\rm m} & F=1\,{\rm N} \\ 1\,{\rm m} & F=2\,{\rm N}\end{cases}
$$
After 2 seconds, we have
$$
x_{new}(t=2\,{\rm s})=\begin{cases}2\,{\rm m} & F=1\,{\rm N} \\ 4\,{\rm m} & F=2\,{\rm N}\end{cases}
$$
The velocities after 1 second would be
$$
v_{new}=v_{old}+at=\begin{cases}1\,{\rm m/s} & F=1\,{\rm N} \\ 2\,{\rm m/s} & F=2\,{\rm N}\end{cases}
$$
So to answer your questions about distances and speeds, you really need to know *how long* the force is applied to the object.

The [joule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule) is the measure of the [work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) the force does after moving the object some height.

Answer (score 2):

> 1 Newton can **move** 1 kilogram 1m
>
> But, can 2 Newtons move 1 kilogram 2 meters?
>
> Is this because 1 Newton = *acceleration* of **1/ms**, so, 2 Newtons would
>   result in a **speed** of 2m/s? Or would it be 1m/s lasting twice as long?
>
> So what does a joule do: **accelerate or just move**?

A joule does *not accelerate*, it is the unit, the measure both of

- **kinetic energy** (that a body has when it has been accelerated and has velocity) and the measure of
- **work** done against a force

1 N (newton) does not move but *accelerates* 1 Kg by 1 m/s **every second**, using the correct units: $1 m/s^2$. 2 N (newtons) give 1Kg *double* acceleration:  $2 m/s^2$. Gravity is a Force of ca.

- **10 N** and **accelerates** 1 Kg by $10m/s^2$ (and not, as you write, 1(0) **/ms**, I edited your post by I left that, as I cannot know if *it is a typo* or what units you really wanted to write). That means that every second its velocity increases by 10 m/s. If it lasts for *a second*, then speed will be 10 **m/s** and KE **50 joules** and it will travel a distance of 5m, if it lasts *two seconds* its speed will be 20 m/s and its KE 200 joules, and so on.

The energy these body acquires is measured in Joules and depends on the *time the force acts* on the bodies. This is the case of 1 (or more) Kg of mass that falls to the ground because of gravity for 1 (or more seconds)

- If on the contrary, you want to *lift up a weight* of 1Kg, then you do **not** accelerate the body but you move it or, better **displace** it, it gains no speed because you are doing work, you are working *against a force* (gravity), and with the *same* amount of energy (*joules*) you can lift a
- k-Kg body by 1m, or a
- .5k-kg-body by 2m, or a
- 2k-Kg body by .5m

That is because joules are the product of *force by displacement*: (Ke) = Work = $\rightarrow = F . d$, so  $\rightarrow k *1 = .5k *2 = 2k *.5$

If you want to lift that body back to the height of 5m, you must apply a force of 10N by 5 metres, and spend the **50 joules** of energy it gained falling down, and that because you fight against a force of 10N over the distance of 5m-

In conclusion: gravity accelerates a body, accelerates it  and gives it energy (*joules*), if *you* want to lift a body, you spend energy (*joules*) to displace/ lift it up, in this case you might say, in approximate language, that: 'joules make a body move*

Answer (score 1):

$F=ma$ so $1N$ accelerates a $1kg$ mass by $1m/s^2$.

It does not mean that it will only move 1 metre.